# Find the list of immediate next directory to the current directory for reaching a destination file?

Tags: linux, directory, path, find

We can find the full absolute path of a destination file using *find* keyword. In my case, I need the list of all immediate next directory to my current location which can lead me to my program log file named *foo.log*

For example, some of the paths may be:

```
current-location/alpha/beta/gamma/foo.log
current-location/apple/banana/foo.log
and so on...
```

For the above case, I need a list of `['alpha', 'apple']` as my result as it contains all the possible immediate next folder to reach the destination file.

I'm new to *Linux*. I know, I can always create a brute force solution as I have the absolute-path as well as the current-path, but any optimized/better solution or any hint/idea in the right direction will do!

EDIT:

I don't want the first distinct folder, just the immediate folder to the current-location

My brute force approach:

```
   result={}
   for all the Absolute-path which can reach foo.log:
       Suffix-path = (Absolute-path - current-path)
       Append the Suffix-path[0] to result
```

Comment: Is the part `current-location` in your input an absolute path? Is `current-location` the same as the output of `pwd`? Please clarify this in your question and show a better example. Is the input some output printed by the `find` command? Then show the `find` command you use. It is easy to strip a leading or trailing string using shell variable expansion. It might be possible to modify the `find` command to make this even easier.

Comment: Yes, current-location is an absolute path and I think the problem statement and the expected answer are mentioned very clearly

Comment: Please add all clarification to the question instead of answering in comments. Of course your problem is clear to you, but not necessarily to everyone else. To me it is not really clear how your problem is related to the `find` tag except that you mention it in your text. As far as I know, the `find` command will print absolute paths only if you supply an absolute path as a parameter for the starting point. It is also not clear what you mean with "a list of `['alpha', 'apple']`". A string that looks like this example? An array in a `bash` script? A list in a Python script?

Comment: Does it matter if we need to return it like list/array/or-whatever to the logic needed to solve this problem?
Also find command is helping the brute force solution approach I mentioned? 
Shrug?
@Bodo

Comment: It would clearly increase the complexity of the solution, yes;  A comma,separated list is easier to output than the list enclosed in square braces w/ the elements in single quotes. Without the formatting detail `find -name foo.log|awk -F'/' '{print $2}'` would suffice, as, given the "sample data" you provided, it spits out `alpha` and `apple` when executed in `current-location`.  Just because you were wordy in your question doesn't make it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about (a bit too verbose):

```sh
find . -type f -name 'foo.log' | sed -nE "s#[^/]+/([^/]+)/.*#\1#p;s#.*#'&'#" | paste -sd, - | sed -s 's/^/[/;s/$/]/'
```

Or alternatively:

```sh
find . -type f -name 'foo.log' -printf '%d %p\n' |awk -F '[ /]' '$1>1 {list=sprintf("%s\047%s\047", ((!list)?"":list ","),$3)} END {print "[" list "]"}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a simpler version of @vgersh99 answer, the concept is the same(*%P* format directive will give you the path directly after the starting-point):

```
find given-location/ -type f \
  -name 'foo.log' -printf %P\\n | cut -f1 -d /
```

You can append the output from find to an array using the += operator:

```
a=(); a+=( \
  $(find given-location/ -type f \
       -name 'foo.log' -printf %P\\n | cut -f1 -d / \
  ) \
); echo "${a[@]}"
```